# Marking a column as "email_sent" once script sends email to avoid duplicate emails

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Here is my code.
I have a spreadsheet with 8 column headers, linked here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZQp9GIzLrkEsOF6k_TwAZeUi7v5u94GBrDEKoB3Wk-8/edit?usp=sharing
I am trying to get column I to have "email_sent" added to it to prevent sending duplicates every time someone submits details to the sheet.  The script is running and sending an email formatted as per the Var = message section but I am having issues with it placing an "email_sent" message in column I and not sending the email on the next trigger of the script. I think it is the "sheet.getRange(rowData + i, 'I2:I1000').setValue('EMAIL_SENT');" section that is not working but unsure what is wrong.

```
function sendEmails() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Email"));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:I1000");
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var rowData = data[i];
var emailAddress = rowData[1];
var recipient = rowData[0];
var message1 = rowData[3];
var message2 = rowData[4];
var message3 = rowData[5];
var message4 = rowData[6];
var message5 = rowData[7];
var emailSent = rowData[9];
if (emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') {  // Prevents sending duplicates
var message = 'Hi ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + message1 + ' ' + message2 + 
',\n\n' + message3 + ',\n' + message4 + ',\n' + message5;
var subject = 'Medical Questionairre Check';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
 sheet.getRange(rowData + i, 'I2:I1000').setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is 
  interrupted
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

 }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add some detail about what errors you're experiencing or what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

To change it an elegant way would be to start at a line of which you know for sure that it is not empty and find from there the last non-blank row with [getNextDataCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection).

Sample:

```js
var notBlank = sheet.getRange("A1");
var lastRow = notBlank.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow():
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 16, column.length, 1).setValue('Processed');
```

This would find the last row before the first blank row (could be an  interdispersed blank row between non-empty rows).

If you want to find the very last row of a sheet, then use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

Sample:

```js
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 16, column.length, 1).setValue('Processed');
```

**Careful:**

Make sure that you really want to set the data into the last non-blank row (this means overwriting already existent data).

Kudos to [ziganotschka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11599789/ziganotschka)'s wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691012/google-script-for-marking-non-blank-rows).

Answer (score 0):

## Fixing EMAIL_SENT Issue

I think this should do it. I changed the getRange() parameters to i+2, 9.  Basically you just want a row and a column.  The column is 'I' which column 9 and the row is normally i + 1 if you started the loop at the top but since you started the loop at row 2 then I think it should i + 2. So check it out.

Lately I've been adding the a check on the MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() to guarantee that I don't run myself out of emails. I also had the message and the subject on the wrong side of the condition.

```
function sendEmails() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Email"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) 
  {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var emailAddress = rowData[1];
    var recipient = rowData[0];
    var message1 = rowData[3];
    var message2 = rowData[4];
    var message3 = rowData[5];
    var message4 = rowData[6];
    var message5 = rowData[7];
    var emailSent = rowData[9];
    var message = 'Hi ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + message1 + ' ' + message2 + ',\n\n' + message3 + ',\n' + message4 + ',\n' + message5;
    var subject = 'Medical Questionairre Check';
    if (emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT' && MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()>0 && emailAddress && subject && message) 
    {       
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 9).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');// Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
     }
  }
}
```

Please be sure that you have a column title in each column including mail_sent column.

Comment: Hi Cooper,Thanks for the response. I have 2 new issues now, isn't that always the way! 1) Found logger file [17-08-28 14:16:27:901 VET] Logging output too large. Truncating output.
[17-08-28 14:16:29:566 VET] emailAddress: subject:Medical 2) however email sent appeared in every box in the column not just the ones with an email address in column B?  Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: I am away from my computer right now I'll be back in about an hour I'll take a look at it

Comment: do you real have a 1000 emails to send and will your remaining daily quota handle that many?

Comment: Sorry not 1000 but contacts are added daily in the next blank row so will only be sending 5 - 10 per day but will need to check whole sheet to see which has and which hasn't been sent already.  Thanks I am now awau from computer so will look later on.  Thank you for your contiunued assistance.

Comment: I think I haven't made it clear.  If there is information in any of the columns A, B OR C then the email needs to be sent out.  Column A, B or C are populated by a seperate sheet in the worksheet but only if one of the answers is No instead of yes.

Comment: I had message and subject on the wrong side of the condition so that's why it wasn't sending.  A is the recipient, B is the emailAddress and C is not used by your code. Other than that I'm just requiring that the subject, message and emailAddress not be empty.

Comment: Hi Cooper, Sorry, so what does this mean to the code?  What do I need to change? ATM it is still entering email sent in email sent column for all 1000 rows, however now no emails are being sent out, although that may be because I have reached my quota for today!

Comment: I don't know what ATM is but at this point this code is only setting column 9 to EMAIL_SENT if it passes the conditions and tries to send an email.  It may be that the entire column was incorrectly set in the past.  But this code is not setting all them unless your deleting all of them and running the code.

Comment: ATM = At the moment, sorry!  OK, I think that may be the issue as I only want it to send an email if there is anything in any of the first 3 columns as they only get populated if there is an error in an entry on the first sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SOPiXhU3KWHpHyZEiDUSk8m5qzO5CyALWio6doQvJ4Q/edit?usp=sharing a link to a mock up.  I have adjusted some of the row numbers to accommodate some changes I made.  i hope it wasn't one of those changes that caused the screw up!

Comment: If your making any changes then you need to update your code so that I know what your doing.

Comment: Sorry, I realised about that which is why I added a link to public sheet and if you go to the script editor you can see the updated one.  I am just having issues for it to check if columns A, B or C are blank if not then it sends an email if blank it sends email out in the order mentioned with rowdata.

Comment: Sorry, I realised about that which is why I added a link to public sheet and if you go to the script editor you can see the updated one.  I am just having issues for it to check if columns A, B or C are blank if not then it sends an email if blank it sends email out in the order mentioned with rowdata. I think i may need to insert an IF statement to check =if(A:A1000 is blank) then if not send email, alternatively use the Email_sent column.  Unfortunately the Email_sent column gets populated in every row for some reason still.

Comment: I don't see any links that work on this page to your spreadsheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SOPiXhU3KWHpHyZEiDUSk8m5qzO5CyALWio6doQvJ4Q/edit?usp=sharing                       In the second comment yesterday.